# Mortgage Pool Price - multiple for loops

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, finance

I am fairly new to R and this is probably an easy problem to solve, but is there a better way to get the diagonal values of the matrix and just get the numerical vector of the 100 different values straight away?

```
n <- 10 # 10 periods
m <- 12
PV <- 7500000
i <- 0.05
N <- 100  # number of market rates 
market.rate <- runif(N, min = 0.01, max = 0.04)
prep.rates <- 0.03-0.06*market.rate
pool.price <- matrix(0,N,N) # one pool price for every market rate and corresponding prepayment rate
for (k in 1:N) { # start the prepayment rates loop
mlc <- 1/sum(sapply(1:(n*m), function(t) 1/(1+i/m)^t)) # mortgage loan constant
mp <- numeric(n*m) ; mp[1] <-  PV*mlc; mp[1] # monthly payments
lb.b <-  numeric(n) ; lb.b[1] <- PV # initial mortgage pool
mp <- numeric(n*m) ; mp[1] <-  lb.b[1]*mlc; mp[1] # monthly payments
ip <- numeric(n*m) ; ip[1] <- i/m*lb.b[1] # interest payments
pr <- numeric(n*m) ; pr[1] <- mp[1] - ip[1] # principal reduction
prep <- numeric(n*m) ; prep[1] <- prep.rates[k]*lb.b[1] # monthly prepayment: some fraction of loan balance
total.p.and.i <- numeric(n*m) # principal + interest + prepayment
total.p.and.i[1] <- mp[1] + prep[1]
lb.e <-  numeric(n*m) ; lb.e[1] <- lb.b[1] - pr[1] - prep[1]

#----- periods 2 to 10 -----
for (j in 2:(n*m)) {
mlc <- 1/sum(sapply(1:(n*m-j+1), function(t) 1/(1+i/m)^t))
lb.b[j] <- lb.e[j-1]
mp[j] <-  lb.b[j]*mlc
ip[j] <- i/m*lb.b[j]
pr[j] <- mp[j] - ip[j]
prep[j] <- prep.rates[k]*lb.b[j]
if (j == n*m) prep[j] <- 0 # no prepayments in the last month
total.p.and.i[j] <- mp[j] + prep[j]
lb.e[j] <- lb.b[j] - pr[j] - prep[j]
}
for (j in 1:N) {
disc.rate <- sapply(1:(n*m), function(t) 1/(1+market.rate[j]/m)^t) # discount rate
pool.price[j,k] <- sum(total.p.and.i*disc.rate)
}
}
f.pool.price <- diag(pool.price)
```

Comment: Could you please explain your question in more detail? Do you want to extract all the values on the diagonal of a matrix?

Comment: Thanks for your response! My goal is to simulate the pool price for 100 different market rates. The prepayment rate is a linear relationship with the market rate. Right now I combine all 100 market rates with all 100 prepayment rates, so I get a matrix with 100x100 values, but I only want to match the first market rate with the first prepayment rate and so on, which is why I think the diagonal values of the matrix are technically what I'm looking for. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
f.pool.price <- numeric(N)
for (i in 1:N) {
  f.pool.price[i] = pool.price[i,i]
}
```

There must be an even simpler way, but I think this should work.